# start-stop-daemon error (Exec format error)

Tags: upstart, ubuntu-14.04, start-stop-daemon

This command is part of an upstart script, which used to work in ubuntu 12.04, 10.04.

> sudo  start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/mk_order_handler.pid --chuid ubuntu --exec  /data2/src/jeapps/sites/crons_index.php workers/mk_order_handler

I just upgraded my system to 14.04 and upstart script stopped working. When I manually executed the start-stop-daemon command I get `Exec format error`.

The only difference I can see is, the script is placed in a separate block device. Will it cause a problem? How could I fix this error?

Answer (score 17):

I just now had the same issue and in my case it was due to that my script lacked the `#!/bin/bash` in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate arguments from the executable path using `--`.

The result would be:

> start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/mk_order_handler.pid --chuid ubuntu --exec  /data2/src/jeapps/sites/crons_index.php -- workers/mk_order_handler

Also, I do not know why you are using `sudo`. Upstart jobs are run as root, so they do not need `sudo`.